# View deleted questions

Tags: discussion

How do I view my own deleted questions? I deleted a terrible question of mine that I now know how to improve. I cannot find the question under the list of questions that I have asked. Is the question gone forever?

Comment: Simply put, if you no longer have the link it's gone forever. However, if you want it back flag another post of yours with the other reason and ask a moderator nicely, explaining _why_ you want it back.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Surely that [tag:status-declined] is out of date?

Comment: No @AndrewC, though the note at the bottom of the question apparently is. You still can't see everything and you still need a link from somewhere if it's not "recent" apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: questions tab]

If you click on your questions tab on your profile,
then scroll down to the bottom, there's a link "deleted recent questions" - try it!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you know when this was added? I noticed it for the first time today and didn't see a reference in any MSO question.

Comment: No, I don't know, but I vaguely remember it being discussed somewhere.

Comment: OoOo, that's new though only _really_ useful if the definition of "recent" is forever...